# Windows: Remote Display Back in Powershell a la X11?

Tags: windows, powershell, display

If I have two Linux boxes, A and B, I can SSH from A to B with X11 forwarding enabled. This allows me to use graphical applications on B and have the display rendered on Machine A.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect in Windows when I'm in a Powershell session? Or do I have to use the graphical console on Machine A and use it to connect to Machine B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Windows GUI is not build like X11 so that method doesn't exist through PowerShell. The Microsoft ecosystem has a few other ways of doing this, look for [app-v](/questions/tagged/app-v) as well as some vendor options. This is not a direct analog of X11 forwarding, it's something else entirely.

Without AppV or similar your best bet really is to RDP into the remote system and run the GUI there.

Comment: if he's just talking powershell doesn't powershell remoting cover what he's looking for?

Comment: @tonyroth So long as what he's doing can be done through command-line. Sounds like the problem is running things like MMCs that don't have powershell hooks.

Comment: @tonyroth I am talking about Powershell remoting. But I want to remote Powershell to Machine B and type, say, 'services.msc' and have the resultant dialog box be for services that are running on Machine B. Currently, the only way I know of to do this is to start 'services.msc' on Machine A, then use the MMC to connect to Machine B.

Comment: yep then @sysadmin1138 is correct.